# Scanner with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

In this program I meant to write that : it should get only positive numbers from user via scanner and if they are positive -  it need to add them to the 'list' Array list.
For some reason it doesn't add the first number when user add it but only the second one (and it runs like this in each while loop).

Can somebody please help?
Thanks! :-)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Second_EX_Advanced_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number ... ");  
        Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (INPUT.nextInt() > 0) {   
            list.add(INPUT.nextInt()); 
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        INPUT.close();
    }
}
```

*

Comment: You are consuming the first integer value in your `while` condition.

Comment: ` while ((value=INPUT.nextInt()) > 0)` where `value` is of type `int` and then `list.add(value);`

Comment: Using nextLine() will clear the buffer, so that the next input you read after an error is going to be the fresh input that's after the bad line you have entered.

Comment: always save input value in some variable,rather than taking input everytime.

Answer (score 1):

you are actually taking the input twice

```
 while (INPUT.nextInt() > 0) { //first time here  
        list.add(INPUT.nextInt()); //second time here
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

change it to

```
int n;
while ((n=INPUT.nextInt()) > 0) { //first time here  
        list.add(n); //second time here
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

now it should work fine;

Answer (score 1):

Error is in while loop of yours:

```
while (INPUT.nextInt() > 0) {   
            list.add(INPUT.nextInt()); 
            System.out.println(list);
        }
```

you are scanning first integer and adding second one, as above.

Here you go with the working code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Second_EX_Advanced_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number ... ");  
        Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        while ((num = INPUT.nextInt()) > 0) {   
            list.add(num); 
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        INPUT.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all :) it helped allot

Comment: Can you accept this answer by clicking on arrow next to the answer. This would be helpful to the community. :)